# How to parse only selected column values using awk

Tags: arrays, unix, awk

I have a sample flat file which contains the following block

```
test my array which array is better array huh got it?

INDIA USA SA NZ AUS ARG ARM ARZ GER BRA SPN
```

I also have an array(ksh_arr2) which was defined like this

```
ksh_arr2=$(awk '{if(NR==1){for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/^arr/){print i}}}}' testUnix.txt)
```

and contains the following integers

```
3 5 8
```

Now I want to parse only those column values which are at the respective numbered positions i.e. third fifth and eighth.
I also want the outputs from the 2nd line on wards. 
So I tried the following

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if(NR >=1 && i=${ksh_arr2[i]}) do print$i ; done}}' testUnix.txt
```

but it is apparently not printing the desired outputs. 
What am I missing ? Please help.

Comment: First: in the IF clause you are assigning a value to the `i` variable.

Comment: I am comparing with the array index value .. right ??

Comment: Second: where have you defined the `ksh_arr2` array?

Comment: No. The comparison operator and the asigning operator are different in `awk`. Read [this link](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Comparison-Operators)

Comment: Any shell array is unknown for `awk` programs. You have to use `-v` option, as Jidder and John1024 have used in their solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How i would approach it

```
awk -vA="${ksh_arr2[*]}" 'BEGIN{split(A,B," ")}{for(i in B)print $B[i]}' file
```

#### Explanation

```
 -vA="${ksh_arr2[*]}"     -    Set variable A to expanded ksh array

  'BEGIN{split(A,B," ")   -    Splits the expanded array on spaces
                               (effictively recreating it in awk)

  {for(i in B)print $B[i]} -  Index in the new array print the field that is the number 
                              contained in that index
```

#### Edit

If you want to preserve the order of the fields when printing then this would be better

```
awk -vA="${ksh_arr2[*]}" 'BEGIN{split(A,B," ")}{while(++i<=length(B))print $B[i]}' file
```

Comment: I think you may have meant `*` rather than `@`: When I tested it, `A="${ksh_arr2[@]}"` expanded out to several strings and did not assign properly.

Comment: @John1024 Oh yeah, didn't realise that would be an issue. Thanks :)

Comment: @John1024 Also i realise that the fact that my answer(and EDIT) were posted after yours and may look like i just copied your answer as they look very similar, i would just like to point out that this is not the case and i was in the process of creating(and Editing) whilst you posted yours. Great minds think alike :)

Comment: Yes, that can happen. Regards

Comment: @Jidder I tried ..awk -vK="${ksh_arr2[*]}" 'BEGIN{split(K,b," ");}{for(i in b)print $b[i]}' testUnix.txt , now it says  awk: String 3 cannot contain a newline character.
Please explain.

Comment: @user3655102 Whats in the array and how did you create it ?

Comment: @Jidder ksh_arr2=$(awk '{if(NR==1){for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/^arr/){print i}}}}' testUnix.txt) the way I created it and it still contains 3 5 8

Comment: Each print creates a newline meaning there will be newlines in the array, so it is not the same as `3 5 8` it is `3\n5\n8\n`

Comment: @Jidder If I want to store the output in a string like tstArr=$(awk '{if(NR==1){s="";for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/^arr/){s=s" "i}}print s}}' testUnix.txt)
and then try to invoke awk
awk -v k=$tstArr 'BEGIN{split(k,a," ");} {for(i in a){print $a[i]}}' testUnix.txt
it says cannot find or open file ?
What's the issue now ?

Comment: Add a comment to your question as i cannot read these comments and don't know what you are talking about, sorry.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65217/discussion-between-user3655102-and-jidder).

Answer (score 1):

Since no sample output is shown, I don't know if this output is what you want.  It is the output one gets from the code provided with the minimal changes required to get it to run:

```
$ awk -v k='3 5 8' 'BEGIN{split(k,a," ");} {for(i=1;i<=length(a);i++){print $a[i]}}' testUnix.txt 
array
array
array



SA
AUS
ARZ
```

The above code prints out the selected columns in the same order supplied by the variable `k`.

#### Notes

- The `awk` code never defined `ksh_arr2`.  I presume that the value of this array was to be passed in from the shell.  It is done here using the `-v` option to set the variable `k` to the value of `ksh_arr2`.
- It is not possible to pass into `awk` an array directly.  It is possible to pass in a string, as above, and then convert it to an array using the `split` function.  Above the string `k` is converted to the `awk` array `a`.
- `awk` syntax is different from `shell` syntax.  For instance, `awk` does not use `do` or `done`.

#### Details

- `-v k='3 5 8'`

  This defines an `awk` variable `k`.  To do this programmatically, replace `3 5 8` with a string or array from the shell.
- `BEGIN{split(k,a," ");}`

  This converts the space-separated values in variable `k` into an array named `a`.
- `for(i=1;i<=length(a);i++){print $a[i]}`

  This prints out each column in array `a` in order.

#### Alternate Output

If you want to keep the output from each line on a single line:

```
$ awk -v k='3 5 8' 'BEGIN{split(k,a," ");} {for(i=1;i<length(a);i++) printf "%s ",$a[i]; print $a[length(a)]}' testUnix.txt 
array array array

SA AUS ARZ
```

Comment: You would want to print `$a[i]` not `i` as that will just be `1-N`

Comment: This does not print the values which are at 3rd 5th and 8th column :(

Comment: @Jidder Thanks.  Answer updated: this should fix the column issue.

Answer (score 0):

`awk 'NR>=1 { print $3 " " $5 " " $8 }' testUnix.txt`